# I can not run Java on Visual Studio Code! I tried a lot

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

My problem is that I can not run Java on Visual Studio Code. I downloaded all extension and JDK but there is an issue and error when I run the code..

I took a screenshot for my problem.

***here is the code:***

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

***here is the error in the terminal:***

```
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\LearnJava>  & 'c:\Users\me\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.26.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\869d91d9e4b3718bf03724a877036fed\redhat.java\jdt_ws\LearnJava_9276adca\bin' 'Hello'
ahl
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop\LearnJava>
```

***here is the error in the output:***

```
Running] cd "c:\Users\me\Desktop\LearnJava\" && javac Hello.java && java Hello

[Done] exited with code=0 in 4.348 seconds

[Running] cd "c:\Users\me\Desktop\LearnJava\" && javac Hello.java && java Hello
ahl

[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.152 seconds

[Running] cd "c:\Users\me\Desktop\LearnJava\" && javac Hello.java && java Hello
ahl

[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.236 seconds

[Running] cd "c:\Users\me\Desktop\LearnJava\" && javac Hello.java && java Hello
ahl

[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.157 seconds
```

Comment: What steps did you follow exactly, extensions, version of  Java SE Development Kit (JDK), etc.? Did you use the installer of Visual Studio Code for Java developers or installed the Java extensions by yourself?

Comment: I don't see any errors here. Is that really the code you are running? Any change you're actually running code that prints "ahl" instead of "hi"?

Comment: 1- I installed ( Java Extension Pack) 2- I installed (Java JDK) 3- I installed ( Java pack in visual studio code)

Comment: If there is no error why I can't see the output in one line like this (hi)? I was following someone on youtube and the output was just one word (hi)

Answer (score 0):

From the outputs you give out, everything works well, partly. Both of debugger and code-runner. The only problem you run across is the outputs are not what you expected. It's more like a cache problem, you can try to create a new .java file, or delete the cache folder:
'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\869d91d9e4b3718bf03724a877036fed'.